# Spring MVC Hibernate OneToMany non Primary key join column cannot be cast to serializable error

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am to create a Spring Restful API using Hibernate, JPA, MapStruct...

I have to main tables :

```
 live_data (id, room_name, occupation,last_change,uuid)
```

and

```
rooms (id, name)
```

My goal is to create a Service that returns all rooms and their live data information but I need to join the two tables by name and not by id.

I created 2 entities :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table( name ="live_data")
public class SensorData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "LiveData_Generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="LiveData_Generator", sequenceName = "LiveData_Sequence") 
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;


    @Column(name="room_name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String roomName;

    @Column(name="uuid") @JsonIgnore
    private String sensor_id;

    @Column(name="occupation")
    private String occupation;

    @Column(name="last_change")
    private long occupationLastStatusChange;

}
```

and

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "rooms")
public class Room extends AbstractEntityWithNameTitleLocation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Room_Generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="Room_Generator", sequenceName = "Room_Sequence")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="room_name", referencedColumnName = "name", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private List<SensorData> sensorData = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class RoomRESP extends Room {

 @Override @RestResource(exported = false)
    public List<SensorData> getSensorData() {
        return super.getSensorData();
    }

}
```

I am also using mapping in my Spring service with mapstruct that calls room.getSensorData();

My problem is that if I try to get my rooms I have an Error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.project.domain.room.model.Room cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
```

And if I make it implement Serializable I get :

```
NoSuchMethodError on getSensorData();
```

Can ANy one help me please

Answer (score 1):

You are mixed directions of relations OneToMany and ManyToOne.

Try this:
In Room class change OneToMany to:

```
@OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roomName")
```

Remove the JoinColumn annotation:

```
@JoinColumn(name="room_name", referencedColumnName = "name", insertable=false, updatable=false)
```

over the sensorData in Room class

In SensorData class add folowing line over the roomName field:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "room_name", referencedColumnName = "name")
```

Comment: Can we map on a String, or do I have to add a room object in sensorData ?

Comment: By mapping on roomName, I have unknow entity

Comment: Also when you replace 'String roomName' to 'Room roomName'?

Comment: Yes, cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable appears again

Comment: I see you use 'data' annotation. If this is a Lombok, overwrite Equals and HashCode in both classes by adding 'EqualsAndHashCode(of={"id"}).

Comment: did that, nothing changed